# Tkinter calculator: How to make 0 disappear when it's your first entry or if a decimal point does not follow

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

Now this may sound confusing, but here is what I have to say.
I have a simple Tkinter calculator which runs smoothly, but say for example when you enter something into the entry and the first entry is a 0 you can continue typing and clog your entry up with instances like 05 + 2, etc., which are incorrect on a math level.  How can you stop this so 0 can only be followed by a decimal point or replaced by other numbers being pressed?
So far just theory and need ideas to get this into code.

Comment: Please provide an example code to reproduce. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why not accept 05 as a valid alternative to 5?

Comment: Do you already have forbidden sequences? For example 5 + + 2? Use the same logic.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson how to do forbidden sequaences